# MacOSX: Discrepencies between task_info/host_statistics and Activity Monitor?

Tags: c, macos, memory

On MacOSX, from C I'm testing task_info/host_statistics to get memory information.

I've red numerous answers/articles/tutorials and the correct way to get, say, free memory system seems to use host_statistics.

It is often said that the total amount of memory available is then computed as:

`vmstat.wire_count + vmstat.active_count + vmstat.inactive_count + vmstat.free_count`

Which is wrong on my system. Pages are missing when you compare with the value returned by

`sysctlbyname("hw.memsize",&memsize,&len,NULL,0) )`.

Total free memory is supposed to be:

`vmstat.free_count`

Again, according to the Activity Monitor, this is wrong, there is ruffly more than 1 GB difference here.

Same for `task_info`, `info.resident_size` returns, for instance 17 MB for my running process while the Activity Monitor report less than 4 MB.

So, who is lying here ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What version of OS X? Have you looked at `struct vm_statistics64` and `host_statistics64()`? It's got additional fields, like `compressor_page_count`. Also, where exactly in Activity Monitor are you looking for system memory stats? At the very least, I believe that you should use `vmstat.free_count + vmstat.inactive_count` to get a good sense of "free memory".

Comment: Also, check the output from the `vm_stat` command and take a look at its [source code](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-643.1.1/vm_stat.tproj/vm_stat.c).